# What's the simplest way to calculate a day of the week forwards or backwards?

Tags: modulus, days

If I want to a calculate a day of the week in the future the result is pretty simple to get:

```
    enum { SUNDAY = 0, MONDAY = 1/*....*/ SATURDAY = 6}

    int getDayInFuture(int currentDay, int numDaysForward)
    {
        return (currentDay + numDaysForward) % 7; 
    }

But I have a function where you can enter a number of days either forward or backward, and I'm having trouble for when calculating a day in the past. The best I've done so far is:



inline int getDayInFutureOrPast(int currentDay, int numDaysForwardOrBack)
{
    int result = (currentDay + numDaysForwardOrBack);

    if (result >= 0) return result % 7; // JUST CALCULATE IT SIMPLY AS NORMAL

    else // GOING BACKWARDS
    {
        int remainder = result % 7;
        if (remainder == 0) return 0; // I HAVE TO ADD THIS SPECIAL CONDITION, IF I DON'T SUNDAY 
                                      // (enum 0) minus 7 days ends up as -7 + (-7 modulo 7) == 7 
                                      // SHOULD BE 0, SUNDAY(0) MINUS 7 DAYS SHOULD BE SUNDAY(0)
        else return 7 + remainder;
    }
}
```

I get the feeling there's a simpler way to do this but I can't think of it.

Answer (score 2):

Summing the currentDay and numDaysForwardOrBack will give the desired day, but it's not in the 0 to 6 range. Using modulo on the sum will give us the remainder of the quotient of Sum/7, but this first modulo operation will still potentially give us a negative result. To eliminate negative results, I add 7 to the result and perform modulo again. This secondary addition operation does not change results that were positive to begin with because the modulo removes the excess, and negative values are shifted up to the positive range.

```
inline int getDayInFutureOrPast(int currentDay, int numDaysForwardOrBack)
{
    int remainder = (currentDay + numDaysForwardOrBack) % 7; // value range is [-6 to 6]
    return (7 + remainder) % 7; //shifts value up to bring value range to [0 to 6]
}
```

Comment: to improve the answer, please give a narrative as to the reason the answer works

Comment: added an explanation